# Переход на другой хостинг

Tags: хостинг, dns, домен

Как поменять хостинг, если доменный регистратор не меняет dns? Поменять хостинг необходимо, так как посещаемость сайта растет и хостинг не выдерживает нагрузку. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, что делать, чтобы не терять домен.

Comment: В чем причина того, что регистратор не хочет менять dns ? Напишите название регистратора, на кого домен зарегистрирован, и сохранились ли данные / документы о регистрации.

Comment: Вот такой ответ от тех.поддержки: http://s020.radikal.ru/i714/1610/d1/cb3143146a93.png

Comment: а собственно немного не понял наверное вопрос сразу. Если Вам нужно сменить только хостинг, Вам же нужно только dns записи изменить, а не делегировать на другой сервис. Или даже для смены записей нужно запрос оформлять ?

Comment: Вот именно даже для смены записей нужно запрос отправить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Узнайте у хостинг-провайдера, к которому хотите перейти, какие значения надо прописать в A и AAAA записях домена, для того, что бы сайт работал с их сервером и пропишите эти значения в настройках домена на тех серверах, где он обслуживается. Потом, когда реестр начнёт функционировать в штатном режиме, сможете выполнить смену NS.

Процесс обновления данных DNS занимает определённое время и сразу после смены A записей некоторые ваши пользователи ещё будут попадать на старый сервер, в то время, как запросы от новых посетителей будут попадать уже новому хостинг-провайдеру. Поэтому желательно вначале разместить сайт у нового хостинг-провайдера и правильно его настроить для работы на новых серверах (в большинстве случаев достаточно сменить данные подключения к БД, но в некоторых случаях может потребоваться поменять и другие настройки в конфигурации CMS).